# Differences between RPM created with rpmbuild and Os-nebula-rpm plugin

Tags: gradle, rpm

I am trying to use the [Nebula rpm plugin for Gradle](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/nebula.rpm) to build RPMs. I am finding the following discrepancy between RPMs built this way and RPMs built the traditional way, with spec files and rpmbuild.

In a spec file, you might have something like this:

```
%dir /usr/local/myapp/logs
```

This would create the directory `/usr/local/myapp/logs` when the rpm is installed.  Once myapp starts to run it would write logs to this directory.  When the app is uninstalled, rpm would understand that the files under `/usr/local/myapp/logs` were not created by the rpm installation process and therefore not delete this directory or the files within it.  If the directory were empty at the time of uninstallation, then the directory would be removed.

There is a similar directive with the Gradle plugin.  If you include

```
directory('/usr/local/myapp/logs')
```

in the build script, this directory will be created similar to the rpm process.  However, in this instance, when the rpm is uninstalled, the directory and any files that have been added within it since installation will be removed.

I am trying to account for this difference.  The RPM plugin is based on the [redline-rpm java package](https://github.com/craigwblake/redline/blob/master/src/main/java/org/redline_rpm/Builder.java), and from looking at the source, and the usual [RedHat rpm documentation](http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-inside-files-list-directives.html), I cannot find any setting that governs this behavior.

Can anyone hazard a guess what might be going on here to create this difference in behavior?

**Update:** [this post](https://www.redhat.com/archives/rpm-list/2008-May/msg00049.html) has some pretty good information on how this works, but I still don't know the name of any directive that alters this behavior.

**Update 2** Now this starts to get very interesting.  If I run `rpm -evv myapp` on the rpm built with the Gradle plugin, after installation, and after having added a file to `/usr/local/myapp/logs`, I see the following:

```
D: fini      040755  2 (7007, 500)      4096 /usr/local/myapp/logs 
D:    erase rmdir of /usr/local/myapp/logs failed: Directory not empty
```

and yet and still, after the operation is complete, the directory is gone!
How can this be?  Could there be some configuration of the rpm executable itself that allows the deletion to take place?

Comment: Wonder if redline or nebula rpm adds any `%postun` directives to force remove folders..

Comment: I don't believe so.  That would be highly irregular and I've never seen any sign of it.  Unless this is a sign of it, but I still don't think so.  :-)  How might I tell except looking at source code?

Comment: After staring at the source, I don't see anyplace where any `%postun` stuff is added.  There might be some strange interaction going on with the `Directives` being passed into the Redline Builder from the os-nebula plugin, but I can't find a good source where the meanings of the values are explained.

Comment: This probably doesn't help, but apparently [this is how](https://github.com/craigwblake/redline/blob/4714595c76c06e8b43bcd93e14478afee3cb341e/src/test/java/org/redline_rpm/ant/RedlineTaskTest.java#L320) redline does `%postun`, and nebula rpm uses that [here](https://github.com/nebula-plugins/gradle-ospackage-plugin/blob/e5ee61891655f20273e1ff2ff5aa19ea2402a080/src/main/groovy/com/netflix/gradle/plugins/rpm/RpmCopyAction.groovy#L91).

Comment: Well, you were right, sort of!  D'Oh!.  Somebody was inserting a default script, but it wasn't Redline, or os.nebula!  It was ME, in my plugin that wraps nebula. LOL.  I had copied some innocent-seeming logic that somebody had put in a spec file, thinking at the time that it made a good default and then forgot about it.  It did an rm -rf.  Make your comment an answer and I'll upvote you.